# GDAL GRID Linear Interpolation Creating a Non Continuous Raster

Tags: gdal, interpolation, tin, delaunay

I am using the GDAL GRID algorithm to create a raster from points using the Linear method. The points I have are generated from the river cross-section lines, and all have the same z value per line. I would expect the algorithm to return a continuous raster, but that is not what I am getting see the image below. It looks like more of nearest neighbor interpolation.

[image]

I checked the documentation, and it states that

> “The Linear method performs linear interpolation by computing a
> Delaunay triangulation of the point cloud,”

I ran the QGIS TIN Interpolation tool to see if it would produce similar results, but it did not. It gave results that I would expect from Delaunay triangulation i.e. a continuous raster. See below

Notice continuous gradient

[image]

I couldn’t find anything in GDAL documentation or on Stackoverflow that would explain why the linear method of GDAL would give a stepped raster. Here is the command and data

```
gdal_grid -l points -a linear:radius=-1.0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -zfield WSEL_REG C:\Users\asiddiqui\Downloads\temp\tin_test\points.shp C:\Users\asiddiqui\Downloads\temp\tin_test\tin.tif
```

[data](https://github.com/ar-siddiqui/curve_number_generator/files/9479319/tin_test.zip)

Comment: Your dataset will make difficulties for many other interpolation tools as well. The distance between lines seems to be around 200 m and between the points on the same line only about 10 cm. That will make the triangles very thin. There are tools which are especially made for bathymetric data. For example this could be worth a trial https://docs.generic-mapping-tools.org/latest/surface.html. Give also the riverbanks as breaklines for the function.

Comment: @user30184 I tried with 10-meter distance between points and the result is the same.